# potential problems with c# with windows 7 due to .net versions

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7

I have written an application that uses await async

works very nice

i have been asked to install it on a windows 7 machine and 
i am afraid it won't work due to .net issues

if the .net is 3.5 what are the recommended ways of action?

Comment: What ".NET issues"? Is there some problem with just installing the latest framework?

Comment: yes. unfortunately this is a factory computer and there are rules against updating it

Comment: what are the .net 35 equivalent of await async?

Comment: I don't believe there is an equivalent.

Comment: there were old ways to doasynchroncity like begin end methods -i ve usedthem before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to use async/await in .NET 3.5. You have a few options:

1. Convince them to let you install at least .NET 4.6. It really won't interfere with anything using .NET <= 3.5 right now.
2. Change your code to .NET 3.5 and just make it work (some features have `Begin` and `End` methods to achieve some sort of asynchronous operations, but not all)
3. Change your code to use .NET Core (and target .NET Core) so you can use all the newest stuff, without having to update the .NET Framework (you copy over only the .NET Core DLLs that you use into the application's folder). Read about [self-contained deployments here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd).